# I cant get state from handleChange function from a check list

Tags: react-native

i m kind of new in React and Javascript in general. I m trying to make a checklist using a checkbox. In the frontend it works, more or less. My problem is that I m trying to get the state if a task is completed or not. I ve made an array with an object, (see MainContent code), but when i click the checkbox it returns in the console.log "undefined".

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

App Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import MainContent from "./components/MainContent";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <MainContent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MainContent Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import task from "../assets/task";
import ListItem from "../components/ListItem";

class MainContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      task: [
        {
          id: 1,
          task: "task 01",
          name: "pedro",
          completed: null
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          task: "task 02",
          completed: null
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          task: "task 03",
          completed: null
        }
      ]
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = completed => {
    alert("your task is", completed);
    console.log("This task is", completed);
  };

  render() {
    console.log("task render", this.task);

    const taskComponents = this.state.task.map(data => (
      <ListItem
        key={data.id}
        task={data.task}
        id={data.id}
        completed={data.completed}
        handleChange={() => {
          this.handleChange();
        }}
      />
    ));
    return <div>{taskComponents}</div>;
  }
}

export default MainContent;
```

ListItem Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
let i = 1;

class ListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ListItem">
        <p style={{ color: i % 2 ? "black" : "orange" }}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.props.completed}
            onChange={() => this.props.handleChange(this.props.completed)}
          />
          Task {i++}: <b>{this.props.task}</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListItem;
```

I would expect to get from the handleChange the state of "completed".
Should i create an empty object to receive the checkbox state?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onChange function should looks like this :

```
(event) => this.props.handleChange(event.value)
```

I'm not sure about the `event.value` but log the event, and the checkbox value should be inside.

Comment: thanks @M.Fazio for the reply. I still not getting the value. i changed the onChange function to `onChange={event => this.props.handleChange(event.value)}`, but it still gives me undefined.

Comment: i tried to console.log(event.value) but it doesn't give me any value. Probably i m calling the log in the wrong place.

Comment: i have the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-dewdney-67lex)

Comment: Just replace `event.value` with `event.target.value`